# No device name for GPU when using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm trying to use my GPU with Tensorflow 2.4.0 but it doesn't seem to find it.

System specs:
Tensorflow version: 2.4.0
Nvidia driver: 460.39, CUDA 11.2
Cuda version: 11.1
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc version: 7.4.0
Python 3.6
GeForce RTX 2080 ti

Added to .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}  
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When I run the following code on a Jupyter notebook (or in the command window) I get the following output:

```
import os  
os.environ['TF_XLA_FLAGS'] = '--tf_xla_enable_xla_devices'  
import tensorflow as tf  
print("Tensorflow version: ", tf.__version__)  
import keras  
print("Keras verion: ", keras.__version__)  
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib  
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())  
print("GPUs: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))  
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())  
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available()) 




Tensorflow version:  2.4.0  
Keras verion:  2.3.0  
[name: "/device:CPU:0"  
device_type: "CPU"  
memory_limit: 268435456  
locality {  
}  
incarnation: 17371587508386671680  
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"  
device_type: "XLA_CPU"  
memory_limit: 17179869184  
locality {  
}  
incarnation: 14652116595346898424  
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"  
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"  
device_type: "XLA_GPU"  
memory_limit: 17179869184  
locality {  
}  
incarnation: 16411682041600468605  
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"  
]
```

Below is what runs in the cmd window:

```
2021-02-21 14:00:44.733163: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.734101: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.760683: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:941] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.761566: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:   
pciBusID: 0000:42:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.545GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 10.76GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 573.69GiB/s  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.761595: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49]  
 Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-02-21 14:00:44.764263: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.764327: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.765316: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.765556: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.765754: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60]   Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64
2021-02-21 14:00:44.766385: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.766524: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.766537: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.  
Skipping registering GPU devices...  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.835456: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:  
2021-02-21 14:00:44.835494: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0   
2021-02-21 14:00:44.835506: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
```

So it looks like TF sees the GPU but isn't using it? I'm not sure what the issue is or why I can't use the GPU. If I try to set the session using

```
with tf.device('/device:XLA_GPU:0')
```

I get the following error:
InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation add: {{node add}} was explicitly assigned to /device:XLA_GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.

But if I use the CPU it works.

Comment: `Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU.`  TF doesn't like your CUDA install.  [My guess would be TF 2.4 is not expecting to use CUDA 11.1, but in fact is expecting to use some other CUDA version, such as CUDA 11.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu). (<-- that is a link you can click on)  In that case, you **cannot** use CUDA 11.1 as a substitute for CUDA 11.0.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks!

Comment: @acornbiscuit, Is your issue resolved after downgrading CUDA 11.0?

Comment: Yes, the issue was resolved.